# Modeling A Food Recipes Database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, data-modeling

I'm trying to design a "recipe box" database and I'm having trouble getting it right. I have no idea if I'm on the right track or not, but here's what I have.

recipes(recipeID, etc.)
ingredient(ingredientID, etc.)
recipeIngredient(recipeID, ingredientID, amount)
category(categoryID, name)
recipeCategory(recipeID, categoryID, name, etc.)

So I have a couple of questions.

- How am I doing so far? Is this design okay from what you all know?
- How would I implement the preparation steps? Should I create an additional many-to-many implementation (something like preparation(prepID, etc.) and recipePrep(recipeID, prepID)) or just add the directions in the recipes table? I would like this to be an ordered list in the UI (webpage).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some thoughts:

You might want to use the same table for Recipe and Ingredient, with a type indicator column.   The reason is that Recipes can contain sub-recipes. Let's call the combined table "Item".  Then your RecipeIngredient table would look like

```
 RecipeIngredient (RecipeId, ItemId, Amount).
```

I'd expect that the table would also have a sequencing column.

If you want to do any calculations with these recipes (e.g., scaling, nutritional analysis, production planning) then your quantities will need to specify a unit of measure. You can do that explicitly (by having a separate column for uofm) or you can use a text field for quantity and expect the user to enter values like "1 cup", or "2 tbs".  If you take that approach, you'll need to make sure that what they enter is recognizable, and parse it every time you need to use it.  This can become surprising complex, especially if you want to represent recipe yields in a formalized manner.

Assuming you want 1:M from recipe to category, I'm still not sure why your RecipeCategory table would have a Name column. I'd think that the name comes from the Category definition.

I agree with Dave that it's unlikely that you'd reuse preparation steps from recipe to recipe, and so a RecipePreparationSteps table (or something like it) would be more appropriate.

However, recipes are often presented with ingredients and instructions intermixed. eg.

Intro text
some ingredients. 
prep instructions
some more ingredients
baking instructions.

To accomodate that, you need to  cleverly set sequencing values in the RecipeIngredient and RecipePreparation step tables so that you can combine data from both in the proper order for presentation.  Another approach would be, instead of these two tables, use a "RecipeLine" table such that each row can represent either an instruction OR an ingredient.  I think that may be what you were suggesting.  Purists would frown on this kind of table overloading, but I'm not a purist.

This is a topic I happen to know a lot about, so ask anything.

Comment: Hi Elroy, Thanks for such a an excellent and loquacious response as I really appreciate it. I was a bit confused by this statement you made "..explicitly (by having a separate column for uofm).." and also the next to last paragraph is something I REALLY would like to do. Could you please help with an example? If you don't mind can I have an email address so that I could email you a pdf version of my current design? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'd be happy to accept your email but I don't want to post my address here.  I'm new to SO.  Don't see a way to email you via your profile.  If you can explain another way to email you, please do, or just post your email address here.

Comment: Thank you. My email address is robert@lewisrb.com. I check that email all the time. You can email me and then I'll reply to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at any of the existing schemas out there, such as [this one](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/recipes/index.htm) at DatabaseAnswers?

Comment: Hi Mitch, I've looked at that schema and I've been trying to understand it for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good start. A few thoughts:

1. Don't see a need for a recpieCategory table.  One-to-many between recipe and category should do fine.
2. A PreparationSteps table should contain 1-n steps for each recipe.  I wouldn't try to reuse steps between recipes.

Comment: I think recipes can be categorised by different aspects, like 'first courses', 'second courses' etc., or like 'soups', salads' etc., or by ingredients , or by cuisine... So a recipe can belong to various categories. But maybe it could be better implemented using tags rather than categories.

Comment: Hi @Andriy-m, I was thinking "tags" when I was thinking categories, but maybe they should be two different things. I went back and fourth with that for a while. Thanks for your input.